# http request shows invalid information python

Tags: python, http

I'm trying to get data from

https://www.biman-airlines.com/bookings/flight_selection.aspx

For example, when I choose flight from Dhaka(DAC) to  Sylhet(ZYL), it goes to

https://www.biman-airlines.com/bookings/flight_selection.aspx?TT=RT&SS=&RT=&FL=on&DC=DAC&AC=ZYL&AM=2018-01&AD=09&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&RM=2018-01&RD=10&PA=1&PT=&PC=&PI=&CC=&NS=&CD=&FS=B4B9631

and shows the flight information

but when I'm trying to perform such get request using python, it shows no info

here is my code:

```
import requests

print(requests.get('https://www.biman-airlines.com/bookings/flight_selection.aspx?TT=RT&SS=&RT=&FL=on&DC=DAC&AC=ZYL&AM=2018-01&AD=09&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&RM=2018-01&RD=10&PA=1&PT=&PC=&PI=&CC=&NS=&CD=&FS=').text)
```

What am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*but when I'm trying to perform such get request using python, it shows no info. What am I doing wrong?*

**The request result shows no info because there is no cookie data in the python HTTP request.**

If you check the HTTP request in browser debug window, you can see there is cookie along with the request -- the cookie identifies who the client is and tells server "Hi, server, I'm a valid user":
[image]

With reasonable guess, in this biman-airlines.com case, the server would check the cookie and return result only if the cookie is valid.

Thus, you need to add your `Cookie` header in the python code:

```
# The cookie below is just for example, you would get your own cookie once visiting the website.
headers = {
    'Cookie': 'chocolateChip=nbixfy44dvziejjdxd2wmzs3; BNI_bg_zapways=0000000000000000000000009301a8c000005000; ASPSESSIONIDSQDCSSDT=PFJPADACFOGBDMONPBHPMFJN'
}

print(requests.get('https://www.biman-airlines.com/bookings/flight_selection.aspx?TT=RT&SS=&RT=&FL=on&DC=DAC&AC=ZYL&AM=2018-01&AD=09&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&DC=&AC=&AM=&AD=&RM=2018-01&RD=10&PA=1&PT=&PC=&PI=&CC=&NS=&CD=&FS=B4B9631', headers=headers).text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I noticed that server sends a head request to /bookings/captcha.aspx  so I try to send head request using `requests.head('https://www.biman-airlines.com/bookings/captcha.aspx').cookies.get_dict()` and pass it to my request, but it seem doesn't work

Comment: in addition, we should pass headers `'X-Hash-Validate': 'value',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' `to the first HEAD request